# Wordpress Migration issues

Tags: php, wordpress, migration

I am trying to copy my wordpress website from domain `http://wwww.example.nl` to `http://www.example.de` . I have used the plugin wp-all-in-one-migrations

After some errors and changing I did the following:

1. Change home and site url in the database in `wp-options`
2. Disable conflicting plugins
3. Edit `config.php` for the right url

The database settings in `wp-config` are also correct and pointing to the right database with the correct settings.

But now I'm unable to login to my new domain `wp-admin`. Sometimes I get `ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED` while trying to reach my new domain or get redirected to the old domain. But sometimes it just works right away (except for logging in)

I don't get errors ( Debug setting is set to TRUE).

How can I find out what's wrong and what direction do I go to fix this problem?
If theres any more information required please let me know and I'll update my question accordingly

Comment: update db connection in wp-config.php

Comment: @AvinashGupta Thank you for your suggestion. This all seems to be correct and pointing to the right database with the right settings. I'll incude it in my question

Comment: if you are running on Apache server you might want to look at your .htaccess file. Also it is always a good idea to regenerate your permalinks (go to Settings-> Premalinks and just update them). It is also possible that you would need to flush your local DNS cache but this is more likely to not help in your case. By the way do you have any redirects from your old domain to the new one? It is always a good idea to have them in terms to save your SEO.